# How to run add-in's (xlam) at opening or close of any workbook that has them installed?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I need to create two "passive" macros that only will work when a certain conditions in a workbook is met (a value in an specific cell).

One macro should run at the openning of the workbook, the other at close.

So, I've created a xlam that does formatting (Create a Report) in which a very hidden tab inputs the value that should trigger the "passive" macros.

I've tried to embed the code inside the Create Report xlam, in the "ThisWorkbook" object. But it's doing nothing since it's trying to run over the xlam. I've already test the codes separately on a test workbook, and since all the codes are embedded in this "test" file, all run correctly.

The reason that I need this to be an xlam or anything similar, is that this will be used by other users and for hundreds of different files.

The code I used for both is something like this:

Disclaimer: the codes were trimmed to show only the main idea of them, so disregard if them had any mistake.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ws As Worksheet

If DoesSheetExists("SettingsTab") Then

    If Worksheets("SettingsTab").Range("G2").Value = "x" Then         

        'Prevent Computer Screen from running
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        'On closing report we hide all tabs except the welcome screen.
        'Access tab is hidden normally and while all others are set to very hidden mode.

        For Each ws In Worksheets

            If ws.Name = "Welcome" Then
                'Skip
            Else

                If ws.Name = "Access" Then
                    Application.Worksheets(ws.Name).Visible = xlHidden
                Else
                    Application.Worksheets(ws.Name).Visible = xlVeryHidden
                End If

            End If

        Next ws


        Application.Worksheets("Welcome").Select

        'Allow Computer Screen to refresh
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True       
     End If
   End If 

  End Sub
```

And the One for opening looks something like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
If DoesSheetExists("SettingsTab") Then

    If Worksheets("SettingsTab").Range("G2").Value = "x" Then   

        'Prevent Computer Screen from running
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        OpenSheets:

        For Each ws In Worksheets

            If ws.Name = "Welcome" Then
                'Skip
            Elseif ws.Name = "Access" Then
                'Skip
            Elseif ws.Name = "SettingsTab" Then
                'Skip
            Else

                Application.Worksheets(ws.Name).Visible = True

            End If

        Worksheets(1).Select


        Next ws
    End If

    End If

    End Sub
```

So my question is, What is the right way to implement my two "passive macros"?

Comment: Use [application-level events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-application-level-event-handler).

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I'm no expert on vba, so this is new for me.

Comment: I edited my comment to be a link to the docs.

Comment: So I've been following along the docs and replicating a similar test, (but mine is showing a MSgBox at close). Then I've created an xlam of this test and added it to excel as a button in the quick access. So, if I click on the icon, when I close it shows the message. The issue here is that I need it to always be running, not only when I click on it. Is there any specific I should input for this to be the case?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the code you're trying now?

Comment: I've already being able to create a xlam that runs at open/close, but for some reason it does the job twice for each. I opened a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60103405/avoid-double-execution-of-application-level-events-in-aa-add-in-xlam)

Comment: Yes I saw... and already upvoted your question :-)