# Avoid double execution of application level events in aa add-in (xlam)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I have a xlam that works at open & close of the workbook.

In order to do this I've created a class module with the next code:

```
''''''''''''''''''''''' Setup Event '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Public WithEvents appevent As Application

''''''''''''''''''''''' Setup Application at Close''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Sub appevent_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)

    MsgBox("The workbook " & Wb.Name & " will close now")

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''' Setup Application at Open''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Sub appevent_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)

     MsgBox("The workbook " & Wb.Name & " is now open")

End Sub
```

Then in the "ThisWorkbook" object I have this code:

```
Dim myobject As New Class1

Sub Workbook_Open()

    Set myobject.appevent = Application

End Sub
```

After installing the Add-in, whenever a file opens two message box appear, one when Excel starts, then one once the file is open, similar case for close.

Why is this happening and How to avoid it?

Comment: Might help to check if the event is firing twice for the same workbook? `MsgBox("The workbook " & Wb.Name & " will close now")` for example

Comment: I've edited the code to implement your suggestion and the first MsgBox is for the Add-in, the second one is for the file itself, something similar happens at close.

Comment: Try adding `If Not Wb Is ThisWorkbook Then`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but try the following:

```
Private Sub appevent_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Wb Is ThisWorkbook Then Exit Sub  ' don't do anything when the add-in opens  
    MsgBox("The workbook " & Wb.Name & " is now open")

End Sub
```

and similarly for `appevent_WorkbookBeforeClose`.

Comment: I tried a similar version of this but a little bit more specific, trying to avoid it running with other .xlam running the next line:

If Not InStr(Wb.Name, ".xlam") > 0 Then